# Call random function Javascript, but not twice the same function

Tags: javascript, function, random

I use a function that randomly selects another function, which works. 
But sometimes it runs the same function twice or even more often in a row.

Is there a way to prevend this?

My current code:

```
window.setInterval(function(){
        var arr = [func1, func2, func3],
        rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length),
        randomFunction = arr[rand];
        randomFunction();
}, 5000);
```

Pretty simple so far. But how do I prevent func1 (for example) to run twice in a row

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply store the index of the last function called and the next time, get a random number which is not the last seen index, like this

```
var lastIndex, arr = [func1, func2, func3];

window.setInterval(function() {
    var rand;
    while ((rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)) === lastIndex) ;
    arr[(lastIndex = rand)]();
}, 5000);
```

The `while` loop is the key here,

```
while ((rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)) === lastIndex) ;
```

**Note:** The `;` at the end is important, it is to say that the loop has no body.

It will generate a random number and assign it to `rand` and check if it is equal to `lastIndex`. If they are the same, the loop will be run again till `lastIndex` and `rand` are different.

Then assign the current `rand` value to the `lastIndex` variable, because we dont't want the same function to be called consecutively.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you, quick response and easy implementation!

Comment: While technically correct, this solution has a chance to spin the loop for a few times if the random value happoens to be the same again.

Answer (score 0):

You can select random values from 0-1. And after every run, swap the recently executed function in the array with the last element in the array i.e. arr[2].

```
var arr = [func1, func2, func3];
window.setInterval(function(){
    var t, rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (arr.length-1)),
    randomFunction = arr[rand];
    t = arr[rand], arr[rand] = arr[arr.length-1], arr[arr.length-1] = t;
    randomFunction();
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about a simple check to prevent picking an index that matches the previous pick?

```
var arr = [func1, func2, func3, ...];
var previousIndex = false;

var pickedIndex;
if (previousIndex === false) { // never picked anything before
  pickedIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
}
else {
  pickedIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (arr.length - 1));
  if (pickedIndex >= previousIndex) pickedIndex += 1;
}
previousIndex = pickedIndex;
arr[pickedIndex]();
```

This will pick a random function in constant time that is guaranteed to be different from the previous one.